# MS Access Pop-Up Reminder

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I am currently working on a school project which is making a Database in Access.

Currently, I am attempting to create a pop-up reminder.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim OS As Integer

**OS= DCount("[OrderNo]", "[qryOutstandingPayments]",
"[ExpectedPaymentDate] <=Now() AND [Complete] =0")**

    If OS= 0 Then
            Exit Sub
                Else
                    If MsgBox("There are " & OS & " uncompleted jobs" & _
                        vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Would you like to see these now?", _
                        vbYesNo, "You Have Uncomplete Payments...") = vbYes Then
                        DoCmd.Minimize
                        DoCmd.OpenForm "OutstandingPayments", acNormal
                Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

So within my Database i have an Order Table which has the Order Details, OrderNo and Paid(Yes or No field). In the Paid field customers have up until 30 days to pay for their order meaning they can place an order and not pay for 30 days.

Therefore, i have created a query in my Database (OutstandingPayments) that lists all of the customers that have not paid within 30 days.

The code above is to try and create a pop up reminder to display how many customers have not paid within 25 days and if the user wants to see what payments these are.

The Line of code with the ** around it is the problem that i have faced. I have tried to do a couple of other methods but i just do not understand how it works.

I know that the entire two lines with the ** around them are more than likely wrong but i can't find anywhere that is helping me. I think if i find a way to make that line right i can fix the rest of the code.

Thank you

Comment: Isn't `qryOutstandingPayments` representing everything that you want to know already? Why are you filtering further with `[ExpectedPaymentDate] <=Now() AND [Complete] =0`? If you execute your `**` line in the immediate window do you get the results you want? What about if you convert to a query?

Comment: qryOutstandingPayments is where i keep all the customers that have yet to pay, so i need some line of code to be able to get the dates in the query, see if any dates are greater than 25 days. i'm not too sure how that line of code works, i've tried research but haven't figured out how to work with it

Comment: Something like `Select OrderNumber from qryOutstandingPayments  where DateDiff("d", OrderDate, now) > 25` ?

Comment: I tried that and I am getting a compile error and it highlights Select

Comment: "highlists" sounds like you tried to execute that as VBA. That's SQL to be entered in a Query window. If that get's the results you are expecting I can write an answer which executes that as VBA.

Comment: Yeah I'm currently working in code builder on Acecss which is in VBA

Comment: VBA is not the place to directly execute SQL. How does it look from the query editor window?

Comment: On Access I went to my main menu > Design view > properties > Click on Load > Code Builder and here you can write in VBA. I'm not working with a query editor.

Comment: Hello, ive currently got the pop up working, it tells me how many unpaid customers there are with this code : OS = DCount("[Paid]", "[OutstandingPayments]", DateDiff("d", OrderDate, Now) > 25) but it is not giving me the customers that havent paid in 25 days. It was only giving me how many customers havent paid in total.

Comment: Please try in a query window (Create > Query Design > SQL View) to try out the query before turning it into a `DCount`. There is not diagnosing what's the matter when you use a `DCount` straight away.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/c70891668e70ecef14587a1045485bc2 i am getting this now so i think there is something wrong witth the calculation, its showing me all the unpaid customers but instead of saying 3 it should say 1

Comment: What happens when you step through your code? Notice how in `DCount("[Paid]", "[OutstandingPayments]", DateDiff("d", OrderDate, Now) > 25)` the where part `DateDiff("d", OrderDate, Now) > 25` is not in quotes? it probably evaluates to `true` and you get everything.

Comment: So should it be in quotes?

Comment: If it's not in quotes think about the execution order and what `DCount` will receive and what it can do with that value.

Comment: does dcount not need to be like this DCount ( expr , domain [, criteria] )

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: OS = DCount("[Paid]", "[OutstandingPayments]", DateDiff("d", OrderDate, Now) > 25) i dont get why this line wont get this line wont calculate 25 days after orderdate

Comment: when you break on that line when you're debugging execute each one of the parameters in the immediate window to see what is actually being passed to `DCount`. You'll see the first parameter (in the immediate window) will evaluate like this `?"[Paid]" --> `[Paid], then `?"[OutstandingPayments]"` --> `[OutstandingPayments]`, then `?DateDiff("d", OrderDate, Now) > 25` --> 'TRUE'. DO DCount sees `DCount("[Paid]","[OutstandingPayments]",true)` which will filter nothing out. ...

Comment: ...This probably is not throwing an error because you have a control named `OrderDate` on your form and that value you is what's being used. When you are debugging and you mouse over `OrderDate` you'll probably see that value for the current record on your form.

Comment: So basically with DCount i cannot filter the customers that have not paid in 25 days?

Comment: You just need to add your filter inside quotes like this: `DCount("[Paid]", "[OutstandingPayments]", "DateDiff('d',[OrderDate], Now()) > 25")` (also note the single quotes used around d). Assuming `Paid` and `OrderDate` are valid fields in `OutstandingPayments`, it should work.

Comment: Also need to fix the `&_` following `jobs` in the MsgBox expression. The compiler should error. I am surprised it even shows in the pasted code. Need spaces: `jobs" & _`.

Comment: That has worked perfectly, thank you very much for your help Brad and Sunknight0!! Sorry for being quite amateur! However, now ive ran into one last thing and i thought this would work but apparently `DoCmd.OpenQuery "OutstandingPayments", acNormal` wont bring it to the query when i click yes on the on the pop up

Comment: @June7 oh i realised that earlier and adjusted it so it wasnt showing an erorr

Comment: Is it open already? Did you minimize it by accident? If it's in design mode I don't thing DoCmd.Open will flip it out of design mode.

Comment: I see, it does open but i thought it would have brought you to the Query but i'll have a look into it to see if it can do that for me

Comment: On a side note, you should you Date(), not Now()